# RxJava2: onErrorResumeNext not intercepting 400 response code

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have below code for error handling.  My issue is that when server sends a 400 error code the onErrorResumeNext is not being called.  Is this expected? I thought onErrorResumeNext would be called when server sends a non 200 code(200-300).

```
public Single adapt(Call c) {
 return ((Single) adapt(c)
         .onErrorResumeNext(new Function() {
         //BELOW NOT BEING EXECUTED ON 400 error from server.
         @Override
         public Object apply(Object throwable) throws Exception {

                 return Single.error(DoSomethingWithException((Throwable) throwable));
                 }
         }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
           .observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .flatMap( response -> {

          }
          );}
```

Comment: Placing breakpoints. I can see that the onErrorResumeNext's apply gets skipped and execution goes to flatMap's response.

Comment: I assume your value in the sequence type is a Response<T> and not T itself, thus the Retrofit call doesn't fail the `Single`. `onErrorResumeNext` works only if the sequence fails.

Comment: @akarnokd it works for other errors like "NoSuchElementException" though.

Comment: Please post the fully typed code of `adapt`.